# Override inherited function visability

Tags: openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts, inheritance, visibility, override

I have a contract that looks like this:

```js
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract SwappableToken is ERC20 {
  constructor(string memory name, string memory symbol, uint initialSupply) public ERC20(name, symbol) {
        _mint(msg.sender, initialSupply);
  }
  function _approve(address owner, address spender, uint256 amount) public override {
        super._approve(owner, spender, amount);
    }
}
```

However, when doing this I get:
`TypeError: Overriding function visibility differs.`

The `_approve` method has visibility of `internal` but I'd like to make it `public` (Why? Well for testing crazy stuff is all. Yes I know that's a terrible idea for production)

Is it not possible to override the visibility of a function from the base contract?

How would I make an ERC20 where anyone can call the approve function for any owner and sender without rewriting the whole contract?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The _approve method has visibility of internal

The whole idea of explicit visibility and modifiers like `virtual` and `override` is to catch developer errors at compile time. So, you'll be at cross-purposes with the compiler's objectives. You'll end up making functional changes to the thing you're trying to test which is usually a step in the wrong direction.

`_approve`

The style guide suggests using `_` for `private` and `internal` function names. Great. There is a corresponding `external` function, `approve()` that is not `internal`. It is part of the ERC20 interface.

Instead of mangling the code for testing purposes, it's usually a good idea to create an accessible function. Something like:

```
function getPrivateResult() ... {
   return _getPrivateResult();
}

function setPrivateThing(args) ... guards .. {
   _setPrivateThing(args);
```

The external `getPrivateResult()` function would be part of the interface (with  `override`) but the interface would be silent on `_getPrivateResult()`.

If you really need a temporary scaffold for testing, consider something like:

```
function deleteMeTestingOnly(args) ... { // signal auditors this should have been removed
  _approve(args);
}
```

That pattern helps you keep faith with the idea that the internal state of a contract should be 100% discoverable from the outside. Also, if you look closely, the `private` function can hold the important logic (once) and there might be multiple routes to it from the outside.

```
function case1(address user) ... onlyTrustedContract ... {
  _setPrivateThing(user);
}

function case2(address user) ... onlyOwner ... {
  _setPrivateThing(user);

function case3() ... {
  _setPrivateThing(msg.sender);
}
```

That helps you avoid a tangled mess of concerns like *only the owner, or one of my contracts, or one of my users and sometimes pass msg.sender and something get an argument, and ... and ...*.

The `private/internal` `_setPrivateThing()` function would not be part of the defined interface, by definition, but the three cases would be.

Hope it helps.